# Seeking recommendations for a computer program that enables conversion from a Libre Office Impress slideshow to an .mp4 video?

Tags: slideshow, libreoffice, mp4

I am seeking recommendations for a computer program that enables conversion from a Libre Office Impress slideshow to an .mp4 video?.

Libre Office Impress cannot export a slideshow to video the way the current version of Microsoft Powerpoint can. Without using Google software, or Microsoft software other than the Windows OS, or any non-free software, how can I convert an LOI-made slideshow offline to a video in .mp4 format?

Comment: On what OS shall it run? As you say "without MS, Google or non-free software", am I assuming correctly that should be Linux then?

Comment: I'd like to know the same as Izzy: does "without Microsoft" mean "not Windows" as well?

Comment: Sorry. I have corrected this. I'm allowing the OS to be from Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

Not truly **converting** but you could potentially set [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/) *(or [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/) & its python bindings)* to record *(one of)* your screen*(s)* as detailed [here](https://www.vlchelp.com/how-to-record-desktop/). Then play through the presentation, full screen on that screen. You would probably need to trim off the first & last few seconds.

- Free Gratis & Open Source
- No MS software
- Cross Platform
- However, a 1 hour presentation will take an hour to process at minimum unless you record faster and then slow down the frame rate.